# how to set value of gridview column as the selected value of dropdown list in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application where the user enters his qualifications using dropdownlist
1. Subject and
2. Grades
upon save the qualifications are displayed in a gridview which has a select column below the dropdownlist.

To edit user needs to select the row that he wants to edit to display the values in respective dropdownlist for subject and grade.

How do I set the selected value of each dropdown based on subject and grade initially selected.

Thanks

Comment: please show us what have you tried.